# How to add Call a phone number link in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add a call specific phone number using `<a href>` tag inside `innerHTML`. I've tried with double and single quotes.

***1st Case*** is not firing at all.

***2nd Case*** it does appear but when clicking on the phone number rather than dialing it closes.

```
 var popDiv = document.createElement('span');
           popDiv.setAttribute('class', 'popDiv');
           popDiv.innerHTML ="It seems you are looking for: " + "<span style='color:#FF0000'>" + getTitle + "</span>" + "<br />" + "Why don't you call me?" + "<a href='tel:01234567890'>01234 567 890</a>";
```

Please find link to the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75rw5j7v/)

Does anyone know what a possible solution would be?

Comment: what is that getTitle? is it a function or variable?

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Can you create a code snippet?

Comment: Try providing more code or create a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so its easier for people to find an answer/error.

Comment: @John The moment you click the phone number your selection goes away. And because the scripts looks for `mouseup` event the popup dissapear. Try giving the function a variable to keep it open until you click somewhere else on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the `mouseup` event's `target` and if it's `h1`, then only remove the `popDiv`. This should work :

```
$("#"+parentContainerId).on('mouseup', function(e){
    if(event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'h1') {
        $('span.selectedText').contents().unwrap();
        $(this).find('span.popDiv').remove();
    }
});
```

Updated **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75rw5j7v/4/)**

Comment: It seems that it solved my issue thanks a million Patel

Answer (score 0):

Just try with that :

```js
 var popDiv = document.createElement('span');
           popDiv.setAttribute('class', 'popDiv');
           popDiv.innerHTML ="It seems you are looking for: " + "<span style='color:#FF0000'>" + getTitle + "</span>" + "<br />" + "Why don't you call me?" + "<a href=\"tel:01234567890\">01234 567 890</a>";
```

and be sure you have not any meta like that :

```
<meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no">
```

Comment: Why should he try this? Was the original problem caused by bad quoting? Did you confirm that this works better? Sorry, just not a big fan of "try this" answers :)

Comment: Hi Peter the issue I am facing is not using the HTML feature of calling the pre-defined phone number. It does close the pop over instead.

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg : because i haven't enough code to test by myself !

Comment: Hi @Anonymous0day I've attached in my post working JSFiddle demo to test

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg was right, i misunderstood your problem ! i'am going  to check it again.